# Formal definition of: "The event $A$ is determinated by $X_0, \ldots, X_T$"

Tags: markov-chains

Given an event $A \subset \Omega$, a Markov chain $(X_n)$ on $\Omega$ and stopping time $T$ what is the formal definition of: "The event $A$ is determinated by $X_0, \ldots, X_T$". I have found this in the proof of Markov property and Strong Markov property on Markov chains book of James Norris and I don't understand the formal meaning.

Comment: $$A\in\sigma(X_0,\ldots,X_n)$$

Comment: @Did Ok, I have modified the question

Comment: $$A=\bigcup_n(T=n)\cap A_n\qquad A_n\in\sigma(X_0,\ldots,X_n)$$